# How can I combine rx.Observable search results from different observables into a single Observable?

Tags: java, android, system.reactive, rx-java

For my android app, I need an Observable that aggregates results from 7 different searches and emit as a single collection.

- for the final emission, I chose `ListMultimap<Content, SearchResult>` where `Content` is an enum for the type of search result and `SearchResult` is a view model interface used to display the search results.

Here is how I did it, but are there RxJava operators that I do not know of that could do this much cleaner?

```
public Observable<ListMultimap<Content, SearchResult>> getSearchResults(final CharSequence charSequence) {
        return Observable.just(charSequence)
                .map(new Func1<CharSequence, ListMultimap<Content, SearchResult>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ListMultimap<Content, SearchResult> call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                        final String searchTerm = charSequence.toString();

                        final ListMultimap<Content, SearchResult> data =
                                MultimapBuilder.enumKeys(Content.class)
                                        .arrayListValues()
                                        .build();

                        for (SearchResult searchResult : SearchBookmarkableRepoImpl.this.getSectionPageSearchResults(searchTerm).toBlocking().first())
                            data.put(Content.SECTION_PAGE, searchResult);

                        for (SearchResult searchResult : SearchBookmarkableRepoImpl.this.getAppendixPageSearchResults(searchTerm).toBlocking().first())
                            data.put(Content.APPENDIX_PAGE, searchResult);

                        for (SearchResult searchResult : SearchBookmarkableRepoImpl.this.getImageSearchResults(searchTerm, ImageType.FIGURE).toBlocking().first())
                            data.put(Content.FIGURE, searchResult);

                        for (SearchResult searchResult : SearchBookmarkableRepoImpl.this.getImageSearchResults(searchTerm, ImageType.TABLE).toBlocking().first())
                            data.put(Content.TABLE, searchResult);

                        for (SearchResult searchResult : SearchBookmarkableRepoImpl.this.getImageSearchResults(searchTerm, ImageType.FORM).toBlocking().first())
                            data.put(Content.FORM, searchResult);

                        for (SearchResult searchResult : SearchBookmarkableRepoImpl.this.getGlossarySearchResults(searchTerm, GlossaryType.ACRONYMS).toBlocking().first())
                            data.put(Content.ACRONYM, searchResult);

                        for (SearchResult searchResult : SearchBookmarkableRepoImpl.this.getGlossarySearchResults(searchTerm, GlossaryType.DEFINITIONS).toBlocking().first())
                            data.put(Content.DEFINITION, searchResult);

                        return data;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here is an example method signature of one of the 7 search methods. Each returns an `Observable<List<SearchResult>>` If RxJava has a better way to do this, I could emit them as individual `SearchResult` instead of as a `List<>`

```
Observable<List<SearchResult>> getSectionPageSearchResults(final String searchWord)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets do it one step at a time.

To make it more general lets say you have an object(=SearchResult) an and enum(=Content) called anEnum.

I've used ArrayListMultimap for a concrete implementation, I haven't used it before so if there are better ways to add object to it please do.

First Step: [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html)`Observable<List<Object>>` to `Observable<ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object>>`

```
    private Observable<ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object>> getMultiListSectionPageSearchResults(final String searchWord, anEnum anEnum) {
    return getSectionPageSearchResults(searchWord).map(objects -> {
        ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object> newList = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        for (Object o : objects) {
            newList.put(anEnum, o);
        }
        return newList;
    });
    }
```

now you have a list in the format you want.

Second Step: create observables for all the data, lets say you have 4

```
    Observable<ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object>> multiList1 = getMultiListSectionPageSearchResults("one", anEnum.ONE);
    Observable<ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object>> multiList2 = getMultiListSectionPageSearchResults("two", anEnum.TWO);
    Observable<ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object>> multiList3 = getMultiListSectionPageSearchResults("three", anEnum.THREE);
    Observable<ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object>> multiList4 = getMultiListSectionPageSearchResults("four", anEnum.FOUR);
```

Third Step: [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) them to one stream (you can also use [concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) to if the order is important to you)

```
        Observable<ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object>> mergedLists = Observable.merge(
            multiList1, multiList2, multiList3, multiList4);
```

Fourth Step: [reduce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html) them to one list, we will use the first list as the one that will hold all

```
        Observable<ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object>> oneList = mergedLists.reduce((l1, l2) -> {
        for (anEnum c : l2.keySet()) {
            for (Object o : l2.get(c)) {
                l1.put(c, o);
            }
        }
        return l1;
        });
```

Last Step: use the data, single() is just to ensure we actually getting one list

```
oneList.single().subscribe(this::doSomething);
```

where doSomething: `private void doSomething(ArrayListMultimap<anEnum, Object> list)`

If you would use regular list the convertions will be much easier as there are already methods that can do it for you like `l1.addAll(l2)` for reduce

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you split your single `Observable` into separate `Observable`s for each search type, you can use one of either the [combining operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables) or the [aggregate operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators) to collect all the results into a single `Observable` again. This would give you the benefit of being able to run the searches in parallel and you could also run an individual search if you ever wanted to.

For example, you could concatenate two `Observable`s like so:

```
Observable o1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
Observable o2 = Observable.just(4, 5, 6);
Observable result = o1.concatWith(o2);
```

The `result` observable would emit `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

Comment: Well the problem is that the result observable emits 6 different items. I need all those emissions to be aggregated at the end into a single `List<Content, SearchResult` observable which contains all my results, and I am not sure how to achieve that

Comment: `toList()` will collect all emitted items and emit a single `List` of those items. You can't have a list with two types (like `List<Content, SearchResult>`), but you could `map()` the emitted items to a `Pair<Content, SearchResult>`, then convert those pairs to a list.

Comment: What about if one of the was Integer and the other one was String? just(1) and just ("2")

Comment: You can always `map()` one of the observables to the other type before concatenating them.